# Sum columns in Count Case MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to total up the columns in a Count Case query. I have the following query

```
SELECT distinct type,
Year(`date_ready`) as Year,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=1 then `type` end) As Jan_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=2 then `type ` end) As Feb_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=3 then `type ` end) As Mar_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=4 then `type ` end) As Apr_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=5 then `type ` end) As May_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=6 then `type ` end) As Jun_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=7 then `type ` end) As Jul_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=8 then `type ` end) As Aug_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=9 then `type ` end) As Sep_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=10 then `type ` end) As Oct_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=11 then `type ` end) As Nov_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=12 then `type ` end) As Dec_Attr
FROM newsuit
GROUP BY Year(`date_ready`), type
```

What I would like is to get a row called Total, then the total for Jan, total for Feb etc. I presume I need a Sum somewhere, but whatever I try seems to give me the total in the wrong column. I'm guessing that maybe I need to wrap the whole query in another, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

If I put Sum(type) as Total in the select, I just get one cell with the total in. All the other things I have tried give me errors.

Cheers....

Additional discovery. I've found that the following addition before the From clause adds totals to each row. This is useful, however I still want to find the totals for the columns :)

```
sum(case when month(`date_ready`) <13 then 1 else 0 end) as Total
```

Further additional discovery....

This gives me the column totals, just need to combine the two queries.

```
Select Sum(PQ.Jan_Attr) As JanTot, Sum(PQ.Feb_Attr) As FebTot,Sum(PQ.Mar_Attr) As MarTot,Sum(PQ.Apr_Attr) As AprTot,Sum(PQ.May_Attr) As MayTot,Sum(PQ.Jun_Attr) As JunTot,
Sum(PQ.Jul_Attr) As JulTot,Sum(PQ.Aug_Attr) As AugTot,Sum(PQ.Sep_Attr) As SepTot,Sum(PQ.Oct_Attr) As OctTot,Sum(PQ.Nov_Attr) As NovTot ,Sum(PQ.Dec_Attr) As DecTot
From
(SELECT distinct type,
Year(`date_ready`) as Year,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=1 then `type` end) As Jan_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=2 then `type` end) As Feb_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=3 then `type` end) As Mar_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=4 then `type` end) As Apr_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=5 then `type` end) As May_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=6 then `type` end) As Jun_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=7 then `type` end) As Jul_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=8 then `type` end) As Aug_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=9 then `type` end) As Sep_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=10 then `type` end) As Oct_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=11 then `type` end) As Nov_Attr,
Count(case when month(`date_ready`)=12 then `type` end) As Dec_Attr,
sum(case when month(`date_ready`) <13 then 1 else 0 end) as Total
FROM newsuit
WHERE Year(`date_ready`) = '2013'
GROUP BY Year(`date_ready`), type) as PQ
```

UPDATE 13/02/2014 - I've solved this one now, sort of. I couldn't get what I wanted in a single query, so in the event, I've run the two queries above and just used PHP to display it all as one table. Seemed to be the simplest way in the end.

If anyone would like to know how I did this, I'll happily post / send the code I used to create the tables and format it for displaying data from multiple queries.

Comment: How about try using a `group` query

Comment: @bjhaid sounds like a plan, would that give me totals?

Answer (score 1):

I was just asking a similar question, why not try this:

```
sum(case when year(`date_ready`) = '2013' then 1 else 0 end) as Total
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT
  suit_type,
  Year(`date_ready`) as Year,
  SUM(IF(month(`date_ready`) = 1,`type`,0)) AS Jan_Attr,
  ...
FROM newsuit
GROUP BY Year(`date_ready`), suit_type
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I get the following error ' #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS Jan_Attr, SUM(IF(month(`date_ready`) = 2,`type`,0) AS Feb_Attr, SUM(IF(m' at line 3'....

Comment: Yeah, I missed a `)`. Try now

Comment: This one gives no error, but also doesn't give the right output either. I'm getting the correct column headers and row names (i.e. Column headers with months, and rows with the distinct values for 'type' however the totals are not appearing at the bottom of the columns, nor are the individual month values appearing in the cells. Grateful for your help though :)